# Call to undefined function OpenApi\scan() using @SWG Swagger Annotation in laravel

Tags: laravel, swagger

I want to use the @SWG annotation on The Laravel, but an error occurs.

> Call to undefined function OpenApi\scan()

this is my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.4",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^6.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.1",
        "zircote/swagger-php": "2.*"
    }
```

and this is my swagger code

```
/**
 *
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *     basePath="/api/",
 *     schemes={"http"},
 *     host="192.168.1.248:8000",
 *     @SWG\Info(
 *         version="1.0.0",
 *         title="Shahab web service api",
 *         description="this api is written to handle frontend requests for Shahab.",
 *         @SWG\Contact(
 *             email="shahab@gmail.com"
 *         ),
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
composer require zircote/swagger-php
```

Update version 3.* default

Done!.